# Perl to parse text file which may or may not be gzipped

Tags: perl, gzip

I'm using Perl to parse a text file which may or may not be gzipped:

```
my $FILE;
if ( $file =~ /\.gz$/ ) {
    open( $FILE, "gunzip -c $file |" ) || die $!;
} else {
    open( $FILE, '<', $file ) || die $!;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open $FILE, "zcat -f $file|" or die $!;
```

**man zcat**

> -f --force
>
> If the input data is not in a format recognized by gzip, and  if  the  option --stdout  is also given, copy the input data without change to the standard output: let zcat behave as cat.

Answer (score 6):

The core module [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) returns a file handle, if the file is uncompressed/unknown defaults to passing a file handle to the original file, this worked for me;

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);

# Random file, plain text, and gzipped
my $file=('file.in', 'file.in.gz')[rand 2];
print "Picked $file\n";

# Get file Handle
my $FILE = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( $file )
            or die "Problem found with $file: $GunzipError";

while(<$FILE>) { print; }
```